# difference between javascript localstorage and angular localstorage($localstorage)?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-local-storage

I am new to angular . Is there any specific resons to use $localstorage(ngStorage)
instead of regular javascript localstorage

What is difference.

Can any one please explain me?

Comment: From the looks of things, HTML5 `localStorage` requires you to serialize non-primitives, whereas Angular `ngStorage` does not.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using regular javascript localStorage to save an object in localStorage every time you have to stringify it, because localStorage only accepts string type data.but if you use ngStorage it will do all `JSON.stringify()` and `JSON.parse()` for you.

Answer (score 0):

ngStorage just wraps localStorage in an angular service, with a different API. One big advantage of doing this is that it is easier to mock localstorage when writing unit tests. The same reason why you use `$window` instead of javscript native `window`.